# Encoding with UTF-16 in Java

Tags: java, file-io, character-encoding, utf-16

I'm trying to read/write a .txt file in UTF-16 so that I can input/output Japanese characters into/from my program. I have read many similar questions, articles and the Java Docs, virtually copied their code and still can't figure out where I am going wrong. If I output it to the console, or whenever I check the contents of the file (using the correct encoding) all I see is a '?' in place of 'あ'.

Application class:

```
public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] s = {"あ"}; //A test String array
    FileReader.write("unicode.txt", "UTF-16", s, false);
    System.out.println("File: " + FileReader.read("unicode.txt", "UTF-16") + " Hard-coded example: あ");
  }
}
```

FileReader class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class FileReader {

  public static String[] read(String fileName, String encoding) {
    ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<String>();
    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName), Charset.forName(encoding).newDecoder()))) {
      for(String s = reader.readLine(); s != null; s = reader.readLine()) {
        content.add(s);
      }
      reader.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
      System.out.println("An IOException(Input) has been thrown.");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return convertToStringArray(content);
  }

  public static void write(String fileName, String encoding, String[] content, boolean append) {
    try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName, append), Charset.forName(encoding).newEncoder()))) {
      for(String s : content) {
        writer.write(s);
        writer.newLine();
      }
      writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("An IOException(appending=" + append + ") has been thrown.");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static String[] convertToStringArray(ArrayList<String> list) {
    String[] array = new String[list.size()];
    list.toArray(array);
    return array;
  }
}
```

Comment: `public void main`... what language is this? Lol4

Comment: Java... oops I see, I missed the static, sorry. In any case the issue still stands because I wrote a different application class that didn't contain the rest of the code for the question. Thank you, I'll fix that now.

Comment: It outputs `[Ljava.lang.String;@74a14482` If I print the obvious contents of the array, I get this: `File: [あ] Hard-coded example: あ`. When inspecting your code, I can't find anything besides three style issues.

Comment: When it outputs to console, I get `File: [Ljava.lang.String;@260b0569 Hard-coded example: ?`

Comment: Your console may simply not support those characters.  Make sure you have the correct fonts and language support installed.

Comment: If your hardcoded example doesn't even show, then posting your entire code is pointless. Thumbs down.